# How should I make variable global for all the pages in PHP

Tags: php

**Question**

I want to make `$associate_name` and `$app_key` global variable so I can access them on any page I want. Below is the code from my header file and the get variables are coming to index page. It works fine on index page as the $_GET data is available but when a user moves onto next page but with the same header file included it throws an error saying **Undefined index**. Please let me know how can I make this variable available on all pages. Thanks!

**Code**

```
$associate_name = $_REQUEST['an'];
$app_key = $_REQUEST['key'];
define('associate_name',$associate_name);
define('app_key',$app_key);

//echo "Sorry but there seems to be a problem in your code. We can't find one of the following: App name or App key";           

$select_associate = "SELECT * FROM associate_account WHERE associate_name='".associate_name."' and app_key='".app_key."'";
$assoc_result = mysql_query($select_associate) or die($select_associate.mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($assoc_result)<=0){
    echo "Oops there seems to be a problem in your iFrame code. Please login into your Associate panel and copy/paste the link again.";
}else{
    $row_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($assoc_result);
    $associate_name=ucwords($row_assoc['associate_name']);
    $app_logo=$row_assoc['app_logo'];
    $app_intro_content=$row_assoc['app_intro_content'];
    $bg_color=$row_assoc['bg_color'];
}
```

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` or call a variable in a page and include that in all pages

Comment: create a script for your constants, e.g. `config.php` and include it at the top of every php script, e.g. `include config.php`, alternatively you could use require and a different method would be to set the constants as session variables.

Answer (score 1):

Put those variables you want as session or cookie data. Otherwise, you would have to resort to the `global` keyword, which is a very bad way of doing things in modern PHP applications.

It would be like this (for session):

```
$_SESSION["myvar"] = <value>;
```

It's a bit more complicated with cookies, but this should get you going ;)

Comment: Of course, you should initialize the session data handler with `session_start()` and a `session_regenerate_id()` run wouldn't hurt, either (for avoiding session hijacking, among other things).

Answer (score 0):

- Have all your `variables/constants` in a separate file may be `constants.php`
  Include that `constants.php` wherever you want to access that variable.
- Use [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) are your choice in case the value is modified. Otherwise (the value is constant from your configuration and not from user's modification, go for [Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)